# auto-complete installation emacs

Tags: emacs, ess, melpa

I am a complete newbie to emacs and I am trying to use Vincent Goulet's  modified emacs (https://vigou3.github.io/emacs-modified-windows/) for my work (mostly `R` programming and `LaTeX`). The modified emacs comes with `ess` installed and I am trying to get auto-complete to work.

I don't see `company-mode` or `auto-complete` in the when I type `M-x package-list-packages` (although I see `auto-complete-[other things]` and `company-[other things]`, and I am not able to install `auto-complete`.

My `.emacs` file is as follows:

```
;; Added by Package.el.  This must come before configurations of
;; installed packages.  Don't delete this line.  If you don't want it,
;; just comment it out by adding a semicolon to the start of the line.
;; You may delete these explanatory comments.
(package-initialize)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ansi-color-faces-vector
   [default default default italic underline success warning error])
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (tango-dark)))
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (auto-auto-indent auto-complete company))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

(require 'package)
(let* ((no-ssl (and (memq system-type '(windows-nt ms-dos))
                    (not (gnutls-available-p))))
       (proto (if no-ssl "http" "https")))
  ;; Comment/uncomment these two lines to enable/disable MELPA and MELPA Stable as desired
  (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa" (concat proto "://melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  ;;(add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa-stable" (concat proto "://stable.melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  (when (< emacs-major-version 24)
    ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
    (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . (concat proto "://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))))
(package-initialize)


(setq ess-use-company t)
```

Any help in getting auto completion of code to work in `R` would be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi - Thanks for your comment, I think after installation of `auto-complete` I am okay with auto-completion, but `?` or `help` automatically opens in a web browser for me, can this behavior be controlled to open in `R` itself? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, yes, `?print` in `R` interpreter will open a web browser, rather than showing help in the interpreter itself.

Comment: This is what is get when I do `(print inferior-ess-help-command)`, then `Ctrl-j` (to get the value of the variable) - `"utils::help(\"%s\")
"
"utils::help(\"%s\")
"`

Comment: Hmm..`getOption("help_type")` gives `"html"`. I changed that in "Rprofile" file at `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.0\library\base\R`, using `options(help_type = "text")` and restarted `emacs`, still the same issue. But if I type the same in the interpreter, I see that the help with `?` now opens in a new buffer.

Comment: Changing the option to text (it was already there, only commented) in `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.0\etc\Rprofile.site` worked!

Comment: Thanks for your help. If you add your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be an issue with ESS but with R options. The R option `help_type` should be set to "text" instead of "html" (which may be default on Windows?). This can be changed by setting the option in your `.Rprofile` configuration file (the user file should be located at `Sys.getenv("HOME")`) by adding `options(help_type="text")`.

Note that your configuration `ess-use-company` is telling ESS to use the `company` backend that comes bundled with ESS and not the `auto-complete` library (two different packages that provide completion in emacs).

You may want to add `(global-company-mode)` to your init file to have completion running all your buffers (or enable it in your ess hook). I would also recommend looking into `company-quickhelp` for info in your completion menu.